# Natural Language Processing Model

Tags: nlp, machine-learning

I'm a beginner in NLP and making a project to parse, and understand the intentions of input lines by a user in english.

Here is what I think I should do:

1. Create a text of sentences with POS tagging & marked intentions for every sentence by hand.
2. Create a model say: decision tree and train it on the above sentences.
3. Try the model on user input:
4. Do basic tokenizing and POS tagging on user input sentence and testing it on the above model for knowing the intention of this sentence.

It all may be completely wrong or silly but I'm determined to learn how to do it. I don't want to use ready-made solutions and the programming language is not a concern.

How would you guys do this task? Which model to choose and why? Normally to make NLP parsers, what steps are done.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly what do you mean with "intention"?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).
There is an online book with a [chapter on tagging](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), and a [chapter on parsing](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html). They also provide models in python.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on NLTK and Bayes

```
import nltk
import random 
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews


documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)),category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)
        ]

random.shuffle(documents)



all_words = [w.lower() for w in movie_reviews.words()]

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())git b

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)


word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]


def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features =  {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features


print((find_features(movie_reviews.words("neg/cv000_29416.txt"))))

featuresets = [(find_features(rev),category) for (rev,category) in documents ]

training_set  =featuresets[:10]
testing_set = featuresets[1900:]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
print("Naive Bayes Algo Accuracy: ",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,testing_set))* 100 )
```